# Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::password_verify()

Tags: php, authentication, fatal-error

I am using a tutorial to create a admin login for a blog. When I click the button to login this error appears:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::password_verify() in     D:\XAMPP\htdocs\ICT PRoject\class.user.php on line 50

I have looked at another answerd question that says the password_verify() function was only included from php 5.0 onwards. However, I checked and my version is php 5.6.8. I don't have any other ideas so any help is greatly appreciated!
Heres the code to the function that the error comes from:

```
public function login($username,$password){ 

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Comment: change this `if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){
` to `if(password_verify($password,$hashed)){
`

Comment: And make sure you understand what `$this` means.

Comment: Who downvoted this question and all the answers with no explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function login($username,$password){ 

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if(password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Password verify is Php function try using it **without** **$this**.
just call the function and check the Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Password_verify() is a built in function, but you are trying to invoke it as a method on the current object. And the function returns a boolean, not 1. Try:

```
if(password_verify($password,$hashed)){
```